# Can you have Fax and ADSL on one line?

Tags: internet, adsl, fax, telephony

I have one phone line, with an ADSL connection on there. If I plug a fax machine into the filter, will it kick me off the Internet when a fax is sent or received?

Answer (score 2):

A facsimile machine, much like a computer modem, is designed to work at voice frequencies. Given that the ADSL filter works with voice frequencies on a normal telephone, it will work fine with a fax machine as well.

Answer (score 1):

not a conclusive answer, but i think you should be fine.

ADSL works at the higher frequencies (which is what the filter filters and splits out) and fax works on the normal voice-frequencies (which is why you can hear it if you accidentally ring a fax machine with a normal phone) so i'd be very suprised if it didnt work